# Android edittext is underlined when typing

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-keypad, android-inputtype

I need to removed underline when type in edit text field in Android. For the first name edit text first letter should be capital so that I have given `textCapSentences`, but in my case I see underline in edittext fields. how to remove that?

I have tried all the combination of `textFilter|textNoSuggestions|textCapSentences`

its my first name edit text:

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/signup_lname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@color/signup_layer_bg2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/signup_lname"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textFilter|textNoSuggestions|textCapSentences"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/custom_cursor" />
```

My screen:

[image]

Comment: I believe this is your keyboard underlining which word it is offering corrections for. Which keyboard do you use?

Comment: See alternative solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62569902

Comment: This solution worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62569902/5646794

Answer (score 15):

`android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"` disabling text autocorrection

Answer (score 13):

None of the other answers were useful for me. This underline is added to suggest words when writing. This is enabled by a setting on your keyboard app (Gboard in my case).

So there are at least three options you can do:

- Do nothing as this is a setting on an external app (Gboard) and is the user who should handle it.
- Ask the user to disable it and show instructions to explain how to do it. This is: To navigate to gboard settings from settings app or also from an opened keyboard and click on the Settings button, then go to "text/spell correction" or similar and disable the first switch: Show suggestion strip
- Remove it by your self. As Gboard adds an UnderlineSpan to the EditableText in EditTexts you can remove it just first looking for it. The underline is added by Gboard at some point between onTextChanged and afterTextChanged so I had to remove it on afterTextChanged method.

  ```
  editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
       }

       @Override
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
       }

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
           for (UnderlineSpan span : s.getSpans(0, s.length(), UnderlineSpan.class)) {
               s.removeSpan(span);
           }

           ...
       }
  });
  ```

If you need to keep any other UnderlineSpan you could mix this solution with this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47704299/6552016

Comment: I'm looking for way to detect whether chars are replaced by Auto Suggestion or not. Checking UnderlineSpan is a good way

Answer (score 9):

Combining your answers this is what actually works for me:

```
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword|textNoSuggestions"
```

Comment: this worked if after typing is finished. But while typing still underline is shown :(

Answer (score 5):

It's the suggestions that are underlining each word.  Try this:

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Answer (score -1):

put this in edit text layout in your .xml file

> android:background="@null"